# Excel counting pairs

Tags: excel

I have 5000 rows.  In column A I have the salesperson , in column B the buyer.  I am trying to find out how many times each combination appear together.  e.g. Did salesman Abe sell to Buyer Bob 33 times, to buyer Carl 19?

Comment: If you don't want to do a PivotTable as Pnuts suggests you can also just combine the values in the next column and do a CountIf statement

Comment: Where were you planning to put the criteria for every possible combination of salesperson and buyer? A [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53c4dc8e-0e5b-4e32-93df-9ca5e7da89ed) should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

ok takes a few extra columns to accomplish this but here goes...screenshot attached first.[image]

First you need to concatenate the two columns (A and B)you want to enumerate in column C (the formula will accommodate a string in case names column is first last with spaces etc.)

> =$A2&" "&$B2

Then in column D use the following formula to determine whether or not the name combination is duplicated but only true for one instance. I'll explain why in a second.

> =$C1<>$C2

Then in column E count the matches.

> =COUNTIF($C:$C,$C2)

After doing all that, filter results by "True" tally for all the True columns is the number of matching rep/customer relationships.